findelementby "style" with vba selenium for scraping web tables
I would like to select the tables only with the same "style" since they are the only tables that interest me since they are always the same even if the page below changes, my VBA listing in Excel.
I don't know if such a code exists:
 FindElement(by.style("border-collapse:_collapse;")

It's still in its embryonic stage and this is my first obstacle

  Sub example()
    Dim Driver As New selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    Dim itab As Object
    Dim td, tr As Object
    
    Dim r, i, contatore As Integer
    
    Cells.Clear
    With Driver
        .Start
        .Get "https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp"
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[2]/div/button[2]").Click
        
    End With
    For Each itab In Driver.FindElement(by.style("border-collapse:_collapse;")
     ' here, then I will have to develop the code for each single tr and td but this will be 
     '  my next step
    next itab
end sub


There are the following ways of finding an element using Chromedriver from VBA - FindElementByClass,  FindElementByTag,  FindElementByXPath,  FindElementByCSS and it is the last one that may help you find by style

The syntax .FindElement(by.style() looks to me like Java or Python and the syntax is different for VBA ChromeDriver

Have a look at this post about finding by CSS Locator.

thanks mt1 I'm self-taught and I don't know many terms, many of them I call "that thing that is used to do that thing", so would CSS be right to search the string for both "style" and "href", but also for "background"?  Tonight I'll try to rewrite it using findelementbycss

What specifically are you trying to accomplish in words, not code? Your first locator isn't found on the page for me when I test it.

I'm trying to identify the tables that interest me that only have that style "border-collapse:_collapse;" which are precisely the tables that I need then extract from these only those with specific bground I think at this point always using findelementbycss

@MT1 I tried as in the link but I couldn't
'.findelementbycss(style="border-collapse: collapse;")'

Driver.FindElementByCSS("table[style*='border-collapse: collapse;']") or Driver.FindElementsByCSS("table[style*='border-collapse: collapse;']") though I would seek a more robust selector list.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors

To select more than one table use Dim we As WebElements ... and then For Each we In .FindElementsByCss("border-collapse:_collapse;")

@MT1 I tried with your solution Dim we As WebElements ... and then For Each we In .FindElementsByCss("border-collapse:_collapse;") but it gives me error: "an invalid or illegal selector was specified"

@QHarr Thanks, I actually need to learn more about CSS but your solution Driver.FindElementByCSS("table[style*='border-collapse: collapse;']") worked, I will never understand the logic table[style*= when I would intuitively write style=, would you be so kind as to explain it to me? Thank you

This may help ... https://cheatography.com/janesh/cheat-sheets/css-selectors-for-selenium-webdriver/

thanks @MT1 you are a wonderful community

You are welcome plinius, come back soon, stay longer. :)
